# How to set child iframe dimension to parent amp-iframe dimensions?

Tags: iframe, amp-html

i replaced iframe elements on a dynamic content page by amp-iframes. Please have a look at following structure. I dont know the size of the iframe, because layout is responsive and content is not static:

```
<amp-iframe width=300 height=200
     layout="responsive"
     sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"
     class="unknown-size">
    <amp-img class="unknown-size" width="300" height="200" layout="responsive" 
src="/images/logo.png" placeholder>
</amp-iframe>
```

The AMP-Iframe is responsive, its working fine. But i have problems with the iframe child elements (like a embeded video). There is a ugly gray distance to bottom, because the child element (iframe) is not fully stretched.

I am not able to remove the redundant gray space below my embed video. Can anyone help me, please?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. With the iframe I included the JW Player, which have a aspect ratio from 16:9.

I add those values to height and width attributes in my amp-iframe, now its working perfectly

```
<amp-iframe width=16 height=9
 layout="responsive"
 sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin">
<amp-img class="unknown-size" width="300" height="200" layout="responsive" src="/images/logo.png" placeholder>
</amp-iframe>
```

Comment: This site gave me the important hint https://www.jwplayer.com/blog/jwplayer-amp-component/